# ANTLR4 generate contextual errors in listener

Tags: compiler-errors, antlr4

I'm building a language with expression processing.  Whenever possible, I'd like to identify as many errors as I can before execution.  For example:

```
foo = -1;
```

This is a unary minus operator followed by an integer.  No problem there.  But this:

```
foo = - "bar";
```

This is a unary minus operator followed by a string.  That's definitely not okay.

Throw in variable lookups, and it gets even more tricky:

```
foo = - bar;
bar = "bar";
```

The grammar for a unary operator looks like this:

```
| <assoc=right> 
  operator=( 
    PLUS 
  | MINUS 
  | NOT 
  ) 
  operand=expression 
  #unaryOperation
```

My code in the listener looks like this:

```
@Override
public void exitUnaryOperation( PolicyParser.UnaryOperationContext ctx ) {
    String op = ctx.operator.getText();
    Operator operator;
    switch ( op ) {
        case "+": operator = Operator.PLUS;  break;
        case "-": operator = Operator.MINUS; break;
        case "!": operator = Operator.NOT;   break;
        default:  operator = null;
    }
    Expression operand = values.get( ctx.operand );
    values.put( ctx, new UnaryOperation( operator, operand ) );
}
```

What I would like to do is compare the operator to the operand and somehow abort the operation if the operator doesn't apply to the operand.  For example, `- false` is not okay, but `! false` is.

As I see it, I have two options:

1. make the grammar smarter, so the parser fails if I try to do something illegal (much easier said than done - tried it, gave up)
2. throw an error if something is clearly amiss.

Only problem is, I can't just throw an exception during the listener.

In reading The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference, I find examples that embed language-specific code into the grammar, which I am unwilling to do.   And I find plenty of examples of what to do if the lexer or parser find errors.  And there is plenty of advice online about moving certain types of checks into the application and out of the lexer and parser.  But I can't find any specific guidance on how to do that, exactly.

What is the recommended way for a listener to generate an error and interrupt the tree walk so we can terminate the processing of the input in the event of a fatal error not identified by the lexer or parser?

Comment: As Mike says below, it's best to place semantic checking after parsing. But you could try to add a listener using [addParseListener​(ParseTreeListener listener)](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html#addParseListener(org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeListener)), and output semantic errors. It would have to be robust enough to handle an incomplete parse tree.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is semantic processing. The parser only does syntactic processing to give you a transformed data structure (the parse tree) you can use for further processing. Checking for things like duplicate variable names, invalid operator sequences etc. is all part of the semantics of your language.

The usual approach is to first parse and check if there was an error. If so then stop processing with an error message. Then do semantic processing (e.g. using a visitor) and if there's a problem report that to the user and stop processing. Only if both stages return no error, you can continue and execute the input.

With this approach it is clear that your second choice is the better one. Don't put too much extra processing into your grammar.

Comment: What you have said matches what I have read, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Does semantic processing with the ability to prematurely exit out require using a visitor?  Or can you do it using a listener?

Comment: If you are using a listener, how do you terminate prematurely?

Comment: @JohnArrowwood you can use both a visitor or a listener to perform sematic checks/validations. An easy way to terminate prematurely is by throwing an exception. But you can also collect all errors and after the tree walk is done, display them all (or a part of them). There is no clear-cut way to do this.

Comment: You can use whatever way you like for semantic processing. It might involve a listener to fill a symbol table, or you just walk over the tree and do some processing as you come along certain nodes. Stopping a walk with a listener is simple: just throw an exception and capture that on the level where you organize your semantic processing.